# Jquery/Ajax related query for like and dislike button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, spring

In my application, I have some user reviews and guest users can view them and choose to like/or dislike them. Part of the current code in jsp is shown below.

```
<div class="row mtop20">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <p class="info">
                        Was this review helpful? <i class=" fa fa-thumbs-up" id="${review.id}"></i>
                        Yes <i class=" fa fa-thumbs-down" id="${review.id}"></i> No <br>
                        <div id="vote_already_${review.id}" style="display: none;">Your have already voted.</div>                                           
                        <div id="vote_recorded_${review.id}" style="display: none;">Thanks for your vote!</div>
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${empty review.helpfulReviewCounter}">
                                    <c:set var="helpfulReviewCounter" value="0"></c:set>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                    <c:set var="helpfulReviewCounter"
                                                    value="${review.helpfulReviewCounter}"></c:set>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose> 
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${empty review.notHelpfulReviewCounter}">
                                <c:set var="notHelpfulReviewCounter" value="0"></c:set>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <c:set var="notHelpfulReviewCounter"
                                                    value="${review.notHelpfulReviewCounter}"></c:set>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                        <c:set var="totalReviewsCounter"
                                            value="${helpfulReviewCounter + notHelpfulReviewCounter}"></c:set>
                        <span>${helpfulReviewCounter} of
                                            ${totalReviewsCounter} users found this review helpful</span>
                    </p>

             </div>
 </div>
```

I am not that good with jQuery and Ajax. I want to call a javascript/jQuery/Ajax method on click on "Like" button (class fa-thumbs-up) which will call the back-end code and if the back-end code results in success then updates helpfulReviewCounter and totalReviewsCounter for the given review.

My technology stack is spring mvc, hibernate, jQuery, ajax, html5, css3.

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with your server-side code without more information, but this JS will hopefully help:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.fa-thumbs-up').on('click', function() {
    $.post('/api/like', {id: this.id});
  });

  $('.fa-thumbs-down').on('click', function() {
    $.post('/api/dislike', {id: this.id});
  });
});
</script>
```

Obviously change the API paths to suit your backend.

Comment: I can handle the server side code. Its just the client side I am strugglng with. As per your code I can see the call to server side on click of the up and down buttons. But it still doesn't show how it will update helpfulReviewCounter and totalReviewsCounter for the given review (once the server side code does its job). Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the template engine? And what are the `<c:` tags? I don't recognise those.

Comment: I am using following taglibs <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I don't think I can help with that, I'm not familiar. Good luck though.

Comment: Thanks for your time Matt